# Assign one enum Type to another enum Type

Tags: ios, swift, swift2

How we can typecast a variable of one enum type to another. I have two Int Enum. And when i create a variable of type First enum and assign some value from second it doesn't allow me. How we can achieve that?

Below is the code

```
enum Sections: Int {
    case initiateZero = 0
    case Air
    case Weight
}

enum SubSections: Int {
    case MaxPath = 0
    case Weight
    case FullWeight
}
```

For getting them.

```
var section = Sections.initiateZero

if isLongForm {
    section = Sections(rawValue: indexPath.section)!
} else {
    section = SubSections(rawValue: indexPath.section)
}
```

Not able to assign them. Please suggest.

Comment: Show the code of both enums please. You can do that if both enums are using the same raw type, but in fact you shouldn't do that

Comment: @alexburtnik can you please look in to code

Comment: Why are you trying to set `SubSection` value to a variable which type is `Section`? How are you going to use `section` variable after that `if-else`?

Comment: mby you need to add variable type label as Any, because section's type is Sections by default or you should create a protocol for both enums.

Comment: If i declare this var as AnyObject it doesn't allow me to typecast there. Only way i found to check them is to declare atleast one enum type var.

Comment: If i declare vairable type any, then it unable to found the case inside the eunm. got error fore case

Answer (score 4):

I can not think of valid usecase, but you might want to use its `rawValue`s:

```
enum Enum1: Int {
    case one = 0
    case two = 1
}

enum Enum2: Int {
    case one = 0
    case two = 1
}

let enum1 = Enum1.one
let enum2 = Enum2(rawValue: enum1.rawValue)

print(enum2)
```

prints:

```
Optional(Enum2.one)
```

Comment: Please see the value infront of rawvalue i need to pass indexpath.section i need to change that thing before doing so

Comment: What do you mean " the value infront of rawvalue"?